# Pentaho 6.1 change context from /pentaho to /

Tags: tomcat

I have a working Pentaho 6.1 installation that will be exposed to the internet over Apache (that is 99% done). I'm having problems with changing the context of the default /pentaho app to /. I found some how-tos, but none helped:

- https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0P0/000/050 - Change the Web Application Name on Tomcat - this was main reference.

The final product should be Pentaho on https://www.domain.com and not on https://www.domain.com/pentaho

Ty very much

Comment: You need to change the document root in Apache.

Comment: When i try to do that over Apache  (ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to /) i get a to many redirects error.

Comment: Please include the Apache configuration.

Comment: <VirtualHost _default_:443>
...
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
 RewriteEngine On
 ProxyPass /pentaho ajp://localhost:8009/pentaho/
 ProxyPassReverse /pentaho ajp://localhost/8009/pentaho/
 RewriteRule /pentaho/(.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/pentaho/$1 [P]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(/pentaho)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/ [R=301,L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Virtualhost>

Comment: This is my conf now, that works (although RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off is not working). When i try to remove /pentaho from  ProxyPass /pentaho and go to /, i get To many redirects.

Comment: Please put the configuration in the question itself, it is too difficult to read from the comments.

Comment: Sry for not commenting sooner, it's been busy. I managed to solve the issue on the apache side. I'll post an answer with my full configuration. It might come in handy for someone wanting to solve the same thing as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my full apache configuration that solved my problem:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain.com
   Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName www.domain.com
        SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA128:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA128:AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4 
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/crt-ca.crt

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
    RewriteEngine On

    ProxyPass /pentaho ajp://localhost:8009/pentaho/
    ProxyPassReverse /pentaho ajp://localhost/8009/pentaho/

    RewriteRule /pentaho/(.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/pentaho/$1 [P]
    RewriteRule ^/$ /pentaho [R]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*);jsessionid= https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(pentaho)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1/ [R=301,L]

</Virtualhost>
```

It might not look pretty, but it does the job. Hope it helps someone.